# How can i do a ajax request on ReactJS?

Tags: c#, ajax, reactjs

Hey guys could you help me with a reactjs ajax request.
A simple example would help I just don't know how to initialize.

Thx.

Comment: Not specific in any way and no attempt to try doing it yourself, these are the kind of things you learn from a tutorial not here.

Comment: Can you get me one please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some example, take a look to this:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html